# how to export MYSQL data to CSV by chunks?

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I have 300 000 rows in a table. how export MySQL data to csv in a chunk of 50 000 rows?

I have an export data in a whole.

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE 'file_0.csv' 
FROM users 
WHERE id BETWEEN 5 AND 50000
```

not working

Comment: Give details about the table you use

Comment: its users table, i tried this, SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file_0.csv' FROM users WHERE id BETWEEN 5 AND 50000, not working

Comment: yes, but some detail about the table structure..

Comment: what was the error ?

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: table details, email, name, password, phone_no, status,created_at,updated_at

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166893/discussion-between-nithin-and-krishnakumar).

Comment: @guigoz No.. His query is good... The into outfile is in the correct place

Comment: @guigoz its wrong, This is the answer: SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/file_0.csv' 
FROM users 
WHERE id BETWEEN 5 AND 50000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
 mysql> show variables like "%secure%";
 +--------------------------+-----------------------+
 | Variable_name            | Value                 |
 +--------------------------+-----------------------+
 | require_secure_transport | OFF                   |
 | secure_auth              | ON                    |
 | secure_file_priv         | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
 +--------------------------+-----------------------+
 3 rows in set (0.23 sec)
```

You can see your setting regarding the "secure_file_priv"

You need to update this setting. And provide the same path in your query too.